# What to do with all the links to pasteall?

Tags: discussion

I'm not a user of this site. I just happened to be doing some cross-site meta research in relation to [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4637/997587), and noticed that a large number of posts on Blender's main site link to `pasteall.org` (over 1.2k ([all](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%22pasteall.org%22&searchOn=3)) ([questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%22pasteall.org%22%20is%3aq&searchOn=3)) ([answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%22pasteall.org%22%20is%3aa&searchOn=3))), and [there are several posts on meta here suggesting it as a file hosting site](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%22pasteall.org%22&searchOn=3).

But when I go to that site, I get redirected to a different, very sketchy looking site.

Has this been discussed before?

- What exactly happened? Did the service move to a different domain? Or is it just gone?
- If the service moved, why not fix all the links and protect readers of blender.stackexchange.com from the sketchy redirect?
- If the service is just gone, what should be done about all those links?

Comment: Wow I had not noticed this., it seems the site is down. Judging by the sketchy redirect I'd wager it is permanent and not some temporary outage. I've always pushed for using [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com) as our de-facto "permanent hosting" but not everyone honored the guideline. Not sure what to do about all the dead links, I suppose the information is lost at this point though it was never "permanent". Editing all the links by hand seems like an insurmountable task to undertake by hand. I'm not aware of any moderator accessible tool to batch find and replace.

Comment: "_an insurmountable task to undertake by hand_" you underestimate my willpower :P I'm a machine and have done much crazier (Ex. SO's script tag burnination... except I don't have edit privs on this site). and yeah, getting the company involved in doing something about this systematically would be good.

Comment: Yeah, it seems something easily scriptable through the site API for anyone skilled. The question is what to replace the links with now. Files in questions don't worry me too much, as the appeal to download those is generally lost shortly after answering the question. Files in answers are more troubling but those seem like a minority. If my search-fu serves me right we have a total of 460 posts with pasteall.org, out of which only 39 are answers. Where did you get the 1.2k?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos whoops. forgot to link. see edit.

Comment: True better query then mine indeed, the answers are still a manageable minority though sitting at [56](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22pasteall.org%22+is+answer). The sister site domain graphicall.org also seems to have found a new owner, so it seems to excludes the possibility of some ransomware or DDoS

Comment: i remember pasteall shutting down a few years ago. It started first as warning that they would stop uploading new files and keep the already uploaded ones for a while, and then warning they would delete all data. I don't remember why exactly, and I stopped using it very quickly, so I didn't even notice what happened to the domain. I guess the owner just stopped paying for it.

Comment: While we're at it, does someone have a backup of blend-exchange files? Let's say GiantCowFilms suddenly and mysteriously disappears - it would be nice to recover from such a blow.